# resignFirstResponder() crashes Swift app after Xcode update

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, resignfirstresponder

For some reason when I try to close the keyboard in my app, it crashes without any error. The issue seems to have occurred because I have just updated to Xcode 6.3 beta 2.

```
@IBAction func viewTapped(sender : AnyObject) {
    //Closes keyboard when user touches screen.

    budgetNameText.resignFirstResponder()
    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, animations: {
      self.valueEnter.alpha = 0
    })
}
```

I commented out the `textField.resignFirstResponder()` line and that seems to fix the issue, but I can't figure out why.

Any ideas?

Comment: Rename your textField to something else, it's a bad idea to name objects as what they are, at least add something in front like inputTextField. That might even fix your problem.

Comment: I gave that a try, and it doesn't seem to fix the issue. I had been meaning to switch the object name for a while anyway though. I'm not sure if this is why I am not getting any errors when it crashes, but the app doesn't automatically open when I click the run button, I have to manually open it (it didn't used to be like this).